# How to change sharepoint (office 365) logo

Tags: sharepoint

I see this post showing how to change site logo in SharePoint.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2150665&seqNum=6

But it seems old version, as with Office 365, it has different options (attached screenshot).

[image]

Can any body suggest how to change the logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should click on the gear menu in the top suite bar and click Site Information which opens the Site Information Panel.

[image]

After that, you can change the look by clicking change below the image and then click Save as below :

[image]

After that, you might need to wait for couple of minutes or hours for this to get reflected, because there is an Office 365 group associated to it.

Comment: Thanks @GautamSheth, it works. But we need to replace logo which definitely requires more space, it seems that its size is fixed. Is there any way how can I make it larger (more width and height) ?

Comment: No,, we cant increase the dimensions. The thing is that this logo is used in multiple locations like Office 365 group, planner, teams, streams, onenote etc, so it wont be possible to increase it unfortunately

Comment: OK thanks @Gautam for your support. I posted another question just now, can you please take a look if you can suggest anything on this also.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615353/sharepoint-online-office-365-where-can-i-find-master-page-code-javascript-cs

Comment: sure, will take a look ! In the meanwhile, could you please accept this as answer if it helped resolve your query :) , cheers, happy to help !

Comment: I understand, thats why I upvoted because it helps, but did not maked as accepted answer because still looking for some way around :) if exists!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the logo from `/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx` through this setting doesn't show in settings menu.

Comment: If I try this URL, it is showing this message. "Sorry, you don't have access.". But I can visit url like "_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx"... I am using SharePoint foundation, in cloud (Office 365). Is it makes any difference?

Comment: Are you site administrator(not tenant admin)?

Comment: Yes I am site Administrator/Owner, I have created this site myself.