# Sharepoint Online (Office 365) - Where can I find master page code/Javascript/CSS

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Hi I am new with SharePoint (working with Office 365 SharePoint online). I see many articles explaining make changes in master page, javascript or css if we need any sort of customization, like change heading color, hide some header etc...

But I am unable to find any sort of code in SharePoint Online (Office 365). How can I achieve such task if I want to hide header or change the font and color for site page title.

Can anybody suggest me the right path I can find the code to change, or is there any limitation for SharePoint online that it will not allow access to such things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the HTML code of the pages, we can use IE or Chrome F12 developer tools.
[image]

By default, SharePoint use the master page seattle.master, if you want to hide header and change color of pages title, you can add the following style into  tag in this master page using SharePoint designer 2013.

```
<style type="text/css">
#O365_NavHeader,#suiteBarDelta{
    display:none;
}
#pageTitle,#pageTitle a{
    color:green !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

If you use SharePoint Online modern site, we can create a custom theme. The article below for your reference.

[Branding SharePoint Modern Sites](http://Branding%20SharePoint%20Modern%20Sites)

Comment: How to save/upload these changes to SharePoint Online in order to take effect. When I try to 'Save' these changes in seattle.master file, I am getting error message "Server Error: Access Denied". Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check your permission, try to use site collection admin to modify the master page.

Answer (score 1):

What is the development model you are using?SharePoint Framework? SharePoint Hosted Add-ins? Or Provider Hosted Add-ins?There are some suggestions:
If you use the SharePoint Hosted Add-ins,open the folder in the path: 'Your solution path/your project name/Pages/Default.aspx',and you can find the code like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
```

The code('MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"') show that the master page on '~masterurl/defaule.master.
so,you can change do this by sharepoint designer, change the default.master page. You can view the Master Page from http://Sharepoint_Site_Name/_layouts/15/DesignMasterPages.aspx

Comment: Actually I am not clear about SharePoint Framework / SharePoint Hosted Add-ins Or Provider Hosted Add-ins.  Let me elaborate my working environment. I do not have any project folder at my PC. Just using online sharepoint (comes with office365). I just login at Office365 (https://www.office.com) and start using SharePoint from there.

Comment: So,you can download a SharePoint Designer on your PC.And you can make some changes in the default master page.